# Question for calculating the standard deviation of 2D Gaussian

Tags: particle-physics, statistics

I have a question about the process of calculating 2D Gaussian standard deviation.
 The process is start with this equation.

\begin{align}
g'(x', y') = \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_x'\sigma_y'}\exp[-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x'^2}{\sigma_x'^2}+\frac{y'^2}{\sigma_y'^2})] \tag{1}
\end{align}

And rotate this $x'$, $y'$ to $x$, $y$ with an angle $\phi$.

\begin{align}
g(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_x\sigma_y\sqrt{1-\rho_{xy}^2}}\exp[-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho_{xy}^2)}(\frac{x^2}{\sigma_x^2}+\frac{y^2}{\sigma_y^2}-\frac{2xy\rho_{xy}}{\sigma_x\sigma_y})] \tag{2}
\end{align}

My question was why we need to convert parameter $(x', y')$ to $(x, y)$ and use equation 2. What I consider as a correct answer is that equation 1 is in the case of parameters are totally uncorrelated and equation 2 is including correlation. So, we can use equation 2 more generally than equation 1. Could you check my conclusion? If I'm wrong, please tell me the reason. 
 My explanation for this topic might be poor...Thank you so much.

Comment: Ah, the meaning of g(x, y) is probability density function of 2D Gaussian distribution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was crossposted to https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/295441